# How to prove the positive definite property of the semidefinite matrix with regularization?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a positive semidefinite matrix $A_{n\times n}$, I want to transform it to positive definite matrix. I plug the following operation to the original matrix:
$$B=A+\lambda I_{n}$$
where $\lambda > 0$. I want to know whether B is positive definite matrix. Could anyone proof it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\neq 0$, $\lambda x^*x>0$ and $x^*Ax\geq0$, so $x^*Bx=\lambda x^*x+x^*Ax>0$.

Comment: You are so smart! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\alpha\geq0 $ is an Eigenvalue of A with corresponding Eigenvector $\vec{x}_{\alpha}$. Then we have $B\vec{x}_{\alpha}=(A+\lambda I )\vec{x}_{\alpha}=\underbrace{(\alpha+\lambda)}_{>0}\vec{x}_{\alpha}$. 
This means that $\vec{x}_{\alpha}$ is also an Eigenvector to $B$ with shifted Eigenvalue $\alpha+\lambda$ which is by contstrution bigger then $0$

Comment: You answer is also right! $(A+\lambda)$ should be $(A+\lambda I)$

Comment: I am sorry that I can only choose one right answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: if you like it, you could still give it a upvote... :)

Comment: I am sorry. I do not have enough reputation, so I can not give it an up vote.